# What a error with Composer

Tags: composer-php

What a error with Composer
here's an error

> Cloning into ''...
>   Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

ssh is installed. And I have access to the repository (bitbuket). I'm cloning it on ssh

Comment: How are you running `composer`? Using `sudo`?

Comment: Which OS are you using? Windows or some kind of Linux?

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried both `sudo` and `sudo su` and without `sudo`.
But in general I always run via `phpstorm`. Phpstorm is started in `root` mode.

Comment: @NicoHaase Ubuntu

Comment: Why do you run stuff with root permissions? That is generally a bad idea and causes problems as the given one. Have you tried running a usual checkout with the exact same permissions?